# PFSENSE Topology w/Cisco L3 Switces

Tags: routing, cisco, local-area-network, pfsense

I have the need to configure a router on a stick variant where I have WAN in (not shown on image) and 2 LAN ports that go to each of the switches shown in the image.

The vlan 'subinterfaces' live on the pfsense box and are currently tied to the physical 'em2' interface. These are vlan1 vlan10 and vlan 100, as of current.

What I need is to get this setup with 2 LAN cables leaving the router that have the same ip addresses and interfaces that the one cable uses currently. `Pfsense` also does `DHCP` for the minute but this will be changed when the new server is configured.

Please can someone explain how I can achieve my desired configuration.

TIA

Edit: (*The configuration is for mass redundancy*)

[image: Desired Topology IMAGE]